# Which Visual Studio 2017 Template type to use to create a VSTS/TFS Build Release Task

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I know this is super basic but for some reason I'm spinning.  I am creating a custom build/release task for TFS 2017.  I've read a bunch of articles discussing how to do this but they never start from "New Project".

I've considered a web app (SPA example in the youTube video in the overview Microsoft's documentation).  The SPA template gives you a ton of folders and plumbing that are not show in the example video.  Using a SPA seems like it would be good for a hub extension but not necessarily for a build and release task?

I've considered using a windows form project?  I think I may need to make a restAPI call so I was wondering where I would run my javaScript?

I've also installed VS Code and tried building from scratch, which works but I like VS 2017.  I would like to keep it simple and not a ton a folders/plumbing I don't need.

I know this has gotta be simple, whats the best VS 2017 Template to use to create a new Custom Build/Release task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default VS template to create VSTS/TFS build task. But you could check extension [VSTS Extension Project Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JoshGarverick.VSTSExtensionProjectTemplates). This extension contains a project template consisting of:

- A simple TypeScript app
- The required vss-extension.json file
- A README containing links to further extensibility help
- The VSS.SDK.js file needed to bring your VSO extension to life
- Several typings to help with referenced libraries (jQuery, Q,
  Knockout, VSS)
- An item template for a build/release task
- A project template for build/release tasks

More information of creating custom build or release tasks, please refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works.  Adding that template is a great option, i didn't know that existed.  If i were to not add that template what would be a good "simple web template" to add files to?  I see in this gitHub that the typeScript project type has been discontinued.  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12531

Answer (score 1):

Build and release tasks are not a type of Visual Studio project. They are JSON and PowerShell or Node JS.

The [TFX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tfx-cli) utility has what you're after. Once it's installed (`npm install tfx-cli -g`), you can run `tfx build tasks create` to generate a template.

Comment: Yes I have this setup and was using visual studio code to create the structure and it's just a flat file structure but in the example YouTube video it shows the guy using visual studio in a csproj?

Comment: @gperrego Are you sure the tutorial you're watching isn't for a Visual Studio extension? There's some disconnect somewhere, because VSTS build/release tasks and extensions are **not** SPAs.

Comment: These seem to be VSTS/TFS Extensions.  This is the overview link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/?view=vsts and the overview Video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzQFvYY0xiM&list=PLe14MLC-Nwy6saThL6NSv2rTtFNpkvfp3 finally the SPA example is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdPKIllR5Iw&list=PLe14MLC-Nwy6saThL6NSv2rTtFNpkvfp3&index=3 Maybe its a way you can but shouldn't create these extensions?

Comment: @gperrego That video isn't for a VSTS build task. Look at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts . That's all you need to do. Note that you don't **need** to package it up as an extension if you don't want to publish it to the Marketplace so other people can use it. You can just use `tfx` to upload the task directly to your organization's account. No extension necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel I'm focused on a different aspect (writing an app to clone build scripts on TFS 2017 U3) but will come back to this soon.  I think you are right, I am onPrem and can probably use the tfx utility.